# Are we vulnerable to Pivotal Spring Framework Vulnerability CVE-2018-1270?

Tags: spring

We are using below list of Spring Framework jar files in the application and we are not using Spring’s websocket or any other form of websocket dependencies in the application and no code references of enabling STOMP support.

Could someone please confirm if we are still vulnerable to CVE-2018-1270?

```
spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Not clear what you are evening asking, give more information

Comment: Additionally below spring jar files are in use in the application  spring-bridge-2.4.0-b31.jar
 jersey-spring3-2.22.1.jar
 xbean-spring-3.7.jar
 jaxws-spring-1.8.jar
 ehcache-spring-annotations-1.2.0.jar
 activemq-spring-5.9.0.jar

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of the 4.3 branch (up to 4.3.15) are affected, you should upgrade to 4.3.16 as recommended. Further information here: https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2018-1270

This only affects you if you use STOMP over WebSockets, otherwise you are not affected.

Comment: I see in that forum same ;  but my question is even if the application doesn't use any webscoket dependencies  is vulnerable ?

Comment: Of course not, if you are not exposing any WebSocket endpoint, you are not affected

Comment: thanks; yes I feel the same as we dont have any websocket endpoints  so we should not be vulnerable but this is not clearly called out in the cve-2018-1270 ;  it was posted with generalized statement without specifying on this .